# Deploy_ovf gives error after calling ImportVApp function in pyvmomi

Tags: pyvmomi

```
spec_params = vim.OvfManager.CreateImportSpecParams()
import_spec = manager.CreateImportSpec(ovfd,
objs["resource pool"],
objs["datastore"],
spec_params)
lease = objs["resource pool"].ImportVApp(import_spec.importSpec)
```

Error : TypeError: 'vim.vm.device.VirtualDeviceSpec.FileOperation' object is not callable

Why is this error coming ? I tried to execute the code provided by pyvmomi on github.